# SQL to find missing "child" records for each record in "parent" table of 1:many relation

Tags: sql

Probably a duplicate but I haven't figured out the right search terms to find it...

I have a "parent" table of properties, a lookup table of contact types (some of which are recommended/expected, some of which are completely optional), and a "child" table of contacts for each property:

```
PROPERTY: propId, propName, ...
CONTACTTYPE: typeId, typeName, typeIsRecommended
PROPCONTACTS: propId, typeId, contName, ...
```

I need to show, for ALL properties, the recommended contacts, including those that have NOT been created for each property. Desired output (assuming 3 recommended contact types):

```
propName,typeName,contName
'Mountain Mall','Manager','Jill'
'Mountain Mall','Engineer','Jane'
'Mountain Mall','Analyst','Jack'
'Central Hotel','Manager','Bob'
'Central Hotel','Engineer',NULL
'Central Hotel','Analyst',NULL
...
```

I can easily do this for a single property with a LEFT JOIN; I can't figure out how to do it for all properties at once. I'm using SQL Server and it's OK if the solution is specific to that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
with s as
(
    select * 
    from property
    cross join contacttype
)
select s.propname, s.typename, pc.contname
from s
left outer join propcontacts pc on pc.typeid = s.typeid and pc.propid = s.propid
```

Comment: Perfect! I was fumbling around with CTEs but just couldn't get the clarity you have provided -- thanks!